# How do I get openMPI to run with gromacs?

Tags: gromacs

When I run the command
`mpirun -np 48 mdrun_mpi -deffnm md -v`, the software works with no error, but it only runs as fast as when I'm using 1 CPU (the computer I'm using has 48). Can anyone provide pointers as to why there is no boost in speed?

Comment: Is your system large enough? GROMACS is so fast on a single core that IIRC you need at least hundreds of atoms per core to see any speedups.

Comment: @SusiLehtola How would I know if it's large enough? My system has ~5000 atoms and gromacs thinks that the simulation will finish in 1 week for just 100 ns of simulation.

Comment: to determine parallel speedup you have to run a sequence of system sizes. Start small and go bigger. 5000 atoms sounds like you should see parallellism... Are you sure the other calculation used only 1 CPU? It might have used shared-memory parallellism (e.g. OpenMP) instead!

Comment: Try `gmx_mpi` instead of `mpirun` - the former works fine for me (Ubuntu 22.04, local compile with CUDA and MPI flags on).

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, thanks for replying. When I run "mpirun -np 48 gmx_mpi -deffnm md -v" I receive this error "HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file gmx_mpi (No such file or directory)"

Comment: You're missing `gmx_mpi`, which you should have if compiled with the right flags, and you should also have a line in your `.bashrc` that adds the right paths to executables and such (see GROMACS installation instructions). If you are doing this via `apt` or similar, you'll need the `gromacs-mpi` package.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Was the last reply by Todd helpful?